# ¿Cómo usar un valor de sessionStorage y luego borrarlo? Se me borra antes de usarlo

Tags: javascript

Verán, mi idea es guardar la dirección de una url dentro de una sessionStorage, luego usarla y borrarla. El punto es que el código que la borra se ejecuta antes de la línea en que la uso. No sé si se hará con promesas o qué, busqué de eso y no me funcionó. Como alternativa podría reemplazar la variable, pero no pasa, se queda fija.

El error es este:

> .index_redirects.php:60 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'indexOf' of null
> at HTMLDocument. (.index_redirects.php:60)

Código que crea la sessionStorage:

```
<?php
$actualPage = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$rutaIndex  = '<script>sessionStorage.setItem("rutaIndex", "' . $actualPage . '");</script>';
$html = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    ';
$html .= print($rutaIndex);
$html .= '
</body>
</html>
';

$cantidad_posibles_de_carpetas_padres = 10;
$padre = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $cantidad_posibles_de_carpetas_padres; $i++) {
    if (is_file($padre . ".index_redirects.php")) :
        header("location: " . $padre . ".index_redirects.php");
    endif;
    $padre .= "../";
}
?>
```

Código que usa la sessionStorage:

```
function borrarStorage() {
  window.sessionStorage.clear();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var rutaStorage = sessionStorage.getItem("rutaIndex");

  if (rutaStorage.indexOf("<?= $ADMIN_HTML ?>") != -1) {
    borrarStorage();
    window.location.replace("./admin/index.php");
  } else {
    borrarStorage();
    window.location.replace("./index.php");
  }
});
```

Comment: Dado que estás usando redirecciones desde PHP, ¿la redirección se abre en una nueva pestaña? Si es así, deberías usar `localStorage`, no `sessionStorage`

Comment: No, se abre en la misma pestaña.